# Thunderbird Contacts with Zimbra server (zindus alternative)

Tags: sync, thunderbird, contacts, zimbra

is there a plug in for thunderbird 24+ that can sync contacts (the address book) 
with a **zimbra** server?

I used zindus but the end of its life left me without sync plug in

reference: [zindus end of life](http://www.zindus.com/blog/2013/07/10/zindus-end-of-life/)